# Razor em arquivo javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tenho um pequeno código que funciona em **_Layout**:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")",
    success: function () {
          //Seu código aqui ...
    }
});
```

Até agora funciona tudo bem, só que **_Layout** está ficando muito grande. então que quero adicionar um arquivo **javascript** e adicionar ela em **_Layout**.

Só que o problema é arquivo do javascript. Ele não reconhece '**@**'.

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não resolve. JavaScript é uma coisa, Razor é outra.

O **@** faz parte da sintaxe do Razor e quer dizer que isso será processado do lado do servidor antes de a resposta ser enviada ao cliente. Os arquivos JavaScript são enviados ao cliente da mesma forma que são escritos, portanto não são pré-processados por um mecanismo como o Razor.

Existem algumas alternativas:

1. Criar uma *view* com a seção de *scripts* e carregá-la no arquivo _Layout, usando `RenderPage`.

   Algo como:

   ```cs
   @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Scripts.cshtml")
   ```
2. Usar uma biblioteca como o [RazorJS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorJS) para pré-processar os arquivos JavaScript.

Comment: A biblioteca **RazorJS** é confiável ? Porque já faz 6 anos sem atualização.

Comment: Não tem como saber, nunca usei. Mas bem provável que ela atenda aos casos mais básicos, como este da sua publicação.

Answer (score 2):

Crie um arquivo .js e coloque seu código:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Action",
    success: function () {
          //Seu código aqui ...
    }
});
```

E ai na sua View Layout, você instancia:

```
@section scripts{
   <script src="caminho do seu arquivo js"></script>
}
```

Não acredito que dê para utilizar Helpers do Razor em arquivos .js.